# Why is the piezo buzzer not making any sound?

Tags: arduino-uno, led, button, sound, piezo

My ciruit:
[image]

My code:

```
// Pin 13 has a LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;
const int buttonPin = 2;


// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() 
{
  bool buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  while (buttonState == LOW)
  {
   digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
   delay(1000);               // wait for a second
   digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
   delay(1000);               // wait for a second
   tone(12,260);
  {
 }
  }
}
```

What I wish to do, is that when the button is pressed, and the Led's start to blink, I want the piezo buzzer to make a sound. I have never worked with them before so I am having troubles getting results. Is it that the setup is wrong or the code needs extra lines than just the `tone(12,260);` that I added?

Comment: General advice: get one thing working at a time. I don't think your button/flash code does what you want, even before you add the buzzer.

Comment: @MarkSmith Is this reference towards my previous question?

Comment: No, to this one.

Comment: Well my whole point of this project is to implement an alarm system. currently it works with the button acting as the alarm switch, led's as the lights and piezo for the sound. From the answer below, I have done this, however I couldn't understand any of the answers from my previous question (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/35177/stop-leds-from-blinking) that allowed me to disable the alarm. That is really the only problem I am facing currently.

Comment: @Utsav Some issues will disappear if you stop using `buttonState` and start using `digitalRead` everywhere instead. You need current state of pin, not the state loaded looooong time ago. The `buttonState` won't magically change a state without any assigment into it!

Comment: Really the important thing is to *understand* what you're doing. You had five answers to your previous question -- you *can* ask for more explanations if things don't make sense. Using code you don't understand will get you into trouble sooner or later.

Comment: @MarkSmith the reason why I dont understand the answers you guys provide is because you think I understand everything and answer questions in a very complex way. You guys change the whole code and I don't understand some of the new "words" that I witness. Trust me, I appreciate all the work and I do want to learn but this is not a homework site so I can't ask small questions and expect a reply. The way I wrote the code above makes complete sense, but when you fiddle with it too much, I cannot understand. Other than that, I thank you and other members of this site who have helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the code and the circuit have problems.

In the code:

• If the `while (buttonState == LOW)` loop is ever entered, it will never be left, because `buttonState`, the controlling variable, does not change within the loop.

The simplest fix is to remove the line `bool buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);` and replace `while (buttonState == LOW)` with `while (!digitalRead(buttonPin))`, which says to loop while `digitalRead(buttonPin)` is not true; ie, while it is false, or low.

• The empty braces, `{ }` at the end of the `while` loop are superfluous and should be deleted.

In the circuit diagram:

• Neither of the leads of the buzzer is attached to the Arduino circuit, so it won't make any sound.  Note, `tone(12,260);` tells the Arduino to use pin 12 for tone output.

To fix this problem, run a wire from pin 12 to one side of the buzzer, and a wire to ground for the other side of the buzzer.

• A blue LED in series with a red LED might or might not turn on when supplied with 5 V.  For example, if the [red LED takes 1.8 V and the blue LED takes 3.3 V to turn on](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2012/resistors-for-leds/), the 5.1 V total is too high to be turned on by 5 V signals.  Remove one of the two LEDs, and move the wires to the other LED to complete a circuit.